# Opinions/alternatives on dell inspiron 15 5570-2890

Tags: laptop, development

I'm looking for a new laptop mainly for programming work. I don't have much knowledge about hardware but what is most important to me is just for the laptop to be fast while starting up and running applications, so I decided some of my requirements would be:

- at least i5 proccessor
- 8gb ram
- at least full hd resolution (helpful when designing websites)

What doesn't have much importance to me:

- whether it has touchscreen or not
- how much it can work without battery
- camera / audio quality

My budget is around 1000$ - $1200 although I know the prices might vary around the world. I bumped onto a Dell Inspirion 15 5570-2890 which has following specs:

- processor : Intel Core i7-8550U
- disk : ssd 256GB
- graphics card : AMD Radeon 530
- RAM : 8GB

I very much like that it has i7 processor, but as I've been looking around other shops and online I saw most of laptops in similar price range have i5 processors and I'm wondering if there is some catch to this laptop or would it be a good deal? Also I'm wondering if there are some options similar to this Dell that you could recommend?

Comment: Do you have requirements about screen sizes? Would 17 be too big or 13 too small? I recently purchased a Dell XPS 15 and would absolutely recommend it, but the specific one I purchased is way out of your budget. Also keep in mind that some generations of the i5 do not have hyper-threading. I think the 8th Gen has it, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'd rather have a bigger screen than a smaller one, but I could propably settle for any as long as it would outperform other laptops in other categories that I care about